# Why do generated DispID start at 0x60020000?

Tags: .net, .net-core, com

When extracting a TLB out of a .NET-COM-Server (using *tlbexp.exe* or *dscom*) each member of a dual (or disp) Interface gets attached a dispatch identifier (DispID). You can define one by yourself applying `[DispIdAttribute]` to each member. However if you don't the numbering starts at 0x60020000.

Why this number? What's the specialty here? Does anyone know?

Comment: Nothing special, only the original Microsoft developers from ~25 years ago would know I guess. Dispids are not required to be unique (some values are reserved). This value is internally named  `BASE_OLEAUT_DISPID`, relevant source code is here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/vm/commtmemberinfomap.cpp#L18

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks for the hint and the source from which this number originates. Maybe the original idea was to provide a means to detect whether a DispID was auto-generated or not.